# How can you make images resized with css look good in IE?

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer

IE6 and IE7 don't scale images nicely in web pages when the images are scaled with css width/height or attribute width/height. I am not sure which algorithm it uses by default, but it's not good.

Scaled images display aliasing artifacts when scaled in these browsers.

Comment: Is this a real question? You posted the answer 2 seconds after the question.

Comment: crescentfresh: It's okay to ask and answer your own question if the information wasn't on the site before. It's better than okay, it's encouraged. Share the knowledge.

Comment: I thought the community would consider this like Rep whoring. For the record I'm not the one who flagged as offensive. I liked the answer (but neither upvoted nor downvoted).

Comment: From the SO FAQ: "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own programming question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question."

Also, there is a "self-learner" badge that you get when you do this a few times.

Maybe they should add a self-answered tag?

Comment: Aha there already is a selfanswer tag. Not widely used (6). I'll start using that in the future and hopefully quell the populist rage!

Comment: jQuery plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965904/ie-thumbnail-pixelation-when-high-resolution-image-is-set-to-small-size

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fortunately there's a way to force IE7 to use the bicubic scaling algorithm (which looks very nice) with a simple css rule:

```
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }
```

The results are great, and it can be done site-wide with this single rule.

For IE6 you're out of luck as far as I know.

Comment: I don't get what's offensive about this.  Asking and answering your own question is a practice that's encouraged on SO.  What would you prefer someone do, keep their knowledge to themselves?

Comment: Thank you! I've been asking & answering my own q's to SHARE KNOWLEDGE and people have been modding me down :(

The SO instructions specifically say that it's OK to do this, otherwise I wouldn't have.

Thanks for the note about IE6, I think I forgot that nugget. I'll edit the orig answer.

Comment: Also I'll point out that I originally got this tip from Joel Splosky's blog, but I think it deserves to be on Stack Overflow!